# Reload data from backend for model with findAll an RSVP.hash

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, emberfire

I struggle a couple of days with ember data (emberfire adapter).
It seems not to be possible to reload the data from the database ?

this is the model :

```
model: function() {
    console.log('In model');
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        customers: this.store.findAll('customer',{reload:true}),
```

This data is diplayed in a ember models-table !
After doing a update of some data i want to reload the model from the server ? But this seems not to be simple ???

1) reload:true (like above) seems not to be working (bug in ember data ??)

2) a action with .reload() seems only to work on record level not on collection level ?

How can i manage it to reload the data from the server ????

Comment: {reload:true} should work ?. is your transition is calling model hook ?..

Comment: How can i do that ? i tought transitionTo skips the model hook ?

Comment: How can i do that ? i tought transitionTo skips the model hook ? I get over the model hook via a refresh() (manually) But no reloading of data ! Find a lot of posts on newsgroups regarding the fact that {reload:true} is not working ? (or are this all old posts ???)

Comment: which version of ember-data your are ?. I am using 2.4.0 for me its getting the data from server. just ensure model hook is called.

Comment: I use 2.7.0 how to you fix it to call the model hook ?  also with refresh ?

Comment: In fact i need the reload because of another known issue in ember data : When i save() my model after createRecord it returns duplicate records in the store, not in the database ! (also a lot of posts regarding this issue) i try to solve this with reloading the data but without success for the moment !

Comment: Some one with  experience in ember-data will provide proper guidance...until then you can just play using,
this.store.unloadAll('customer'); - this will unload all the records in store. useful for workaround
this.refresh() - from routes.(after saving record you call refresh it will run model hook)
unloadRecord() - after saving you can unload records and refresh from route.